# Xamarin Android back button is not working

Tags: xamarin, navigation, back-button

I had build a Multipager Xamarin App, but after second page Android back button and Navigation back button is not working.

I had tried Shell Backbuttonbehavior , but with this only Top Navigation back button is working

```
<Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
            <BackButtonBehavior Command="{Binding BackCommand}" IconOverride="back.png"    />
</Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
```

I had tried overriding OnAppearing and OnDisappearing to set Current and pervious navigation but that too is not triggering on thrid page

```
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            Shell.Current.Navigating += Current_Navigating;
        }

        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
            Shell.Current.Navigating -= Current_Navigating;
        }



        private async void Current_Navigating(object sender, ShellNavigatingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Models.PatientPlannerData.moveNext == false)
            {
                Shell.Current.Navigating -= Current_Navigating;
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..", true);
            } 
          
        }
```

For Navigation from one page to another I am using

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(Page2));
```

Everything is working fine till second page, from third page back button is not triggering

Answer (score 0):

For the Android back button, after compilation the Navigation Bar that we call in Xamarin Forms, turns into the Action Bar for Android during runtime.

Set the toolbar after `LoadApplication(new App());` in `OnCreate` of MainActivity.

```
            AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar toolbar
         = this.FindViewById<AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

And then overrode `OnOptionsItemSelected()`. When you press the backbutton on navigation bar, this event would be triggered.

```
 public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
   
     }
```